# What is a true way to move component from one DOM element to another in context of transcluding?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I have a accordion component. The component has togglable content that is actually `<ng-content>`. I have a form component that should to appear after accrodion's title, in its content. So I want to use only one form component for all accordion items. How to do this?

What I mean:

```
<template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="items">
  <accorion [title]="item.title">
    <my-form></my-form>
    <!-- So it will put multiple my-form components. -->
    <!-- But I want to insert the form dynamically. -->
  </accorion>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code? I don't get what the problem is. Where is `<ng-content>`?

Comment: I will try to give you the code later, I don't have real code for accordion now. Just want to understand it is possible or not. Accordion component would have `<ng-content>` in its template. So in the example above `<my-form>` would be transcluded in it.

Comment: I think a similar approach to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468 might work for you.

Comment: Thanks, not the same that I wanted but it will be useful anyway!